# Generalized Heron's formula for n-dimensional "n-angle" instead of "triangle"

Tags: geometry

Is there a generalized version of Heron's formula for calculating the equivalent of a "volume" of an n-dimensional "n-angle" based on the length of it's sides? I've seen the equivalent formula for a tetrahedron, but I'd like to keep extending the shape by adding an extra point that connects to all existing points in the next dimension.

Does that make sense?

Comment: n-angle $\mapsto$ [simplex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex) $\:$ ? $\;\;\;$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.  See  [Cayley-Menger Determinant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html)